# Using math in browser using XML data

Tags: javascript, xml, json, xquery

I'm trying to make pull XML or Csv data into a HTML file then I want to use math to add up the values and show the result on the page ( I'm basically trying to display invoices on a web browser)

My skill set is HTML/CSS and I understand a little JavaScript

I've managed to pull XML data into HTML using http request and style that information using xslt

Really what I'm asking is what is the best solution to my needs is it using the above method then using xquiry to add up values or would I need to learn a bit of Ajax, Json and calculate the values with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You really should learn AJAX in order to fetch and manipulate data instead of fetching presentation parts. That's the way everyone follows as it allows more responsive interactions with the user and a cleaner architecture in case of complex interactions.

But that doesn't mean you must abandon XML : originally AJAX was built on XML (the X in AJAX) and not JSON.

Personally I prefer JSON, and I think it will be easier to manage in the long term, but if the server side is hard to change, you can fetch the XML (look for example at jquery's ajax function), build javascript objects using it, and then change your screen using those data. If later you decide to use JSON instead of XML, you'll just have to change the "parsing" part of the client code.

Comment: Thanks for your help time to hit the books!

Comment: There are many tutorials on ajax. I suggest you look at jquery : it is very used for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm trying to make pull XML or Csv data into a HTML file then I want to use math to add up the values and show the result on the page"

You can do this with either XSLT or javascript. However, with XSLT things can become pretty complicated, depending on what version you're using. XSLT 1.0 has pretty limited set of functions for aggregating results. For all XSLT, you can't reassign variables you'll have to solve many of these things with recursion. In my opinion, not really a comfortable method.

Regardless of the choice between XSLT and Javascript, I would also question the architecture that would put this kind of logic in the presentation layer in the browser. I think it would be better if the server side would perform all the calculations that are required, and limit the browser's tasks to styling the output.